# how to seperate each data from a php post reply result

Tags: c#, json

I am calling a PHP function from c# as below

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    string URL = "http://site.or/services/LoadMemberData.php";


    NameValueCollection formData = new NameValueCollection();
    formData["id"] = "123";


    byte[] responseBytes = client .UploadValues(URL, "POST", formData);
    string responsefromserver = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);
    Console.WriteLine(responsefromserver);

}
```

once it completed the `responsefromserver` contain the some error message in case of error or details of the member in case of success
as below

```
{"result":{"success":true,"message":"","errorcode":0},"response":{"id":"123","full_name":"tom Vin","mobile_no":"02343434","phone_no":null,"country_code":"123312","country_of_residence":"","email":"ff@gmail.com","passport_no":"hedf"}}
```

how can i seperate the result into variables?

Comment: Use JSON serializer like JSON.Net and deserialize it into a class instance

Comment: Is there a special reason for creating **two** WebClient instances?

Comment: @SirRufo its my typo error..sorry for that..edited the question

Comment: @SirRufo any sample codes available?

Comment: You will find a lot at JSON.Net docs, a ton on the web and also in the answer from Aleks. You really need more?

Comment: @SirRufo thanks i got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate your models by [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) tool like this:

```
public class Result
{
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public int errorcode { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string full_name { get; set; }
    public string mobile_no { get; set; }
    public object phone_no { get; set; }
    public string country_code { get; set; }
    public string country_of_residence { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string passport_no { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Result result { get; set; }
    public Response response { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize your input with `Newtonsoft.Json` library:

```
var input =
    "{\"result\":{\"success\":true,\"message\":\"\",\"errorcode\":0},\"response\":{\"id\":\"123\",\"full_name\":\"tom Vin\",\"mobile_no\":\"02343434\",\"phone_no\":null,\"country_code\":\"123312\",\"country_of_residence\":\"\",\"email\":\"ff@gmail.com\",\"passport_no\":\"hedf\"}}";
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(input);
```

EDIT: Based on @Sir Rufo comment: you can generate your models with [jsonutils.com](http://jsonutils.com/). This site allow you to generate data annotations like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class Response
{
    [DataMember(Name="full_name")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }
```

so you can have a convenient C# naming for your fields

Comment: http://jsonutils.com will do a much better job on class generation. It can also add JsonProperty attributes if you opt in

Comment: Oh, it's allow Pascal case! Thanks a lot, now it be my favorite tool